# Prevent selection being greyed out in iframe in Firefox without using contenteditable

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, iframe, selection

In Firefox 3 and later (and probably older versions), selecting content within an iframe always seems to use the grey selection background colour used for a document that doesn't currently have focus, even if the iframe does have focus. The only exception I have been able to find is when the content within the iframe is editable. This is not the case in other browsers. Here's an example illustrating this:

http://jsfiddle.net/97Vjz/

This unfortunately prevents styling the selection within an iframe using the [`::-moz-selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/::selection) CSS pseudo-element because it only applies to non-grey selections:

http://jsfiddle.net/YYXSY/1/

My question is: is it possible to prevent an iframe's selection being grey in Firefox **without** using `contenteditable` / `designMode`?

### UPDATE

This only seems to happen on dynamically written iframes: using a separate file and the `src` attribute solves the problem. However, I do need it to work with dynamically written iframes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce the problem with a "real" page as iframe content and then it works like you want: blue colored selection! (FF 5.0)

see: http://jsfiddle.net/97Vjz/8/

It seems only generated content has this problem, so you could make a page (php/asp(x)) that generates the content for you to circumvent the problem.

Another solution to use javascript generated content is to load it with `src="javascript:'<html />'"` (actually this is Tim's own solution from the comments below.)

A simple example script: http://jsfiddle.net/97Vjz/9/

```
 iframe.src='javascript:\'<html><body>' + content + '</body></html>\'';
```

Comment: You're right, thank you. Interesting. I do need it to work with a dynamically created iframe though. I shall do some more research.

Comment: Just loaded a page from another domain, and it does not have the problem. Only your js-generated content does this, I even tried with exactly the same content (doctype, xmlns etc), generated from javascript, and still greyed out selections...

Comment: Interesting variation: http://jsfiddle.net/u42cq/. Possibly could be used to create an empty shell page which is then populated using DOM methods rather than `document.write()`.

Comment: Firefox "View frame source" is empty for the iframe as a result of this, but it works. Nice solution, should even work in IE

Comment: I added the src="javascript:'html'" solution to my answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a property of the iframe exposed in Firebug's DOM inspector `contentDocument->designMode` which is set to false for you iFrames.  Forcing it to true through the DOM inspector enables the blue highlight you're after.

Comment: I might be wrong but his question states he would in fact *not* like to use `contenteditable`.

Comment: I actually mentioned `designMode` in the question. It does the same job as `contentEditable` for a whole document, and is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Hypothesis: It seems that for dynamically written iFrames, either a XUL Iframe is rendered or the Gecko engine doesn't honor the styles.

Short of submitting a bug, the only workaround I can see is to wrap our contents in a `textarea` and style it to make it 'invisible': http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/YYXSY/19/

Comment: It's a reasonable workaround up to a point, but I really need HTML content inside the iframe, not just text within a textarea.

Comment: well, yeah. i was suggesting to wrap text only. you can still have html around it with the inner text wrapped in textarea.