# Selection changes color when Firefox loses focus

Tags: firefox, css, selection, pseudo-element

I'm setting the selection background color via CSS:

```
::selection {
  background:#cc0000;
  color:#fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
  background:#cc0000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

On most browsers when the focus is somewhere else (like an IFrame), the selection color will stay the same, e.g.:

[image]

but on Firefox it won't:

[image]

You can see this in action on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/paleozogt/yVjfu/).

How can I get Firefox to set the selection color in this case?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6730814/prevent-selection-being-greyed-out-in-iframe-in-firefox-without-using-contentedi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get Firefox to set the selection color in this case?

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to do so.

> Is this a bug?

Nobody (including Mozilla themselves?) can say for sure; this was never specified while `::selection` was still in the CSS3 spec. I can't find any information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3A%3Aselection) <del>or bug reports on [bugzilla.mozilla.org](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org) on this either.</del> but I did find [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=541311), which has apparently been left unresolved since being reported in 2010.

This may be clarified in the future, e.g. if `::selection` returns in UI 4.

Comment: Do they have plans for fixing the bug? This is already two years later and I am still experiencing this bug in the latest version of firefox!